# Occurrence of of a word at the end of string - underscore.js

Tags: underscore.js

I have 2 arrays

```
array1 = ["e4dfda158c82cc931e2479e32bde42defacebook", "5824fb40c4a97e21ef9715ea69c1cfb9twitter", "6da098061f82c215f37a4949b1555e26linkedinpage"]
array2 = ["facebook", "twitter", "linkedin", "xing", "weibo", "instagram", "googleplus", "pinterest"]
```

I want to compare these 2 arrays and to get out put like the following

```
output = ["facebook", "twitter", "linkedin"]
```

Tried and working - i need an underscore.js way of doing the same

```
array2.forEach(function(data) {
    array1.forEach(function(data2) {
         n = data2.indexOf(data);
         if(n!=-1) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods used: [chain](http://underscorejs.org/#chain), [map](http://underscorejs.org/#map), [find](http://underscorejs.org/#find). `.value()` is part of chain.

```
var output = _.chain(array1).map(function (el1) {
  return _.find(array2, function (el2) {
    return el1.indexOf(el2) > 1;
  });
}).compact().value();
```

### [JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/lasajanepo/1/edit?js,console)

Since multiple operations are be done on the array the chain method is used just for looks you can always do the next operation by assigning the result array of the first operation to a value then sending that array into the appropriate next operations function call as an argument.

**Map**:

> Produces a new array of values by mapping each value in list through a transformation function (iteratee). The iteratee is passed three arguments: the value, then the index (or key) of the iteration, and finally a reference to the entire list.

Map returns a new array that is the same length as the old array sent into it. It iterates each value of the old array and pushes a new value to the new which is returned by the transform function.

**Find**:

> Looks through each value in the list, returning the first one that passes a truth test (predicate), or undefined if no value passes the test.

the truth test is determined true or false by the return value of the "predicate" callback function you pass in.

The nice thing about iterating with the values with find is once underscore has found a match it will know to stop iterating the array and save precious computation time.

**Compact**:

> Returns a copy of the array with all falsy values removed. In JavaScript, false, null, 0, "", undefined and NaN are all falsy.

Compact changes the length of the array. That may not be what you want to do especially if you are dependent on your result array being the same as the source array. Compact does filter out all undefined data.

If you don't plan on using compact you won't need the chain at all and your code would just use the map like this:

```
var output = _.map(array1, function (el1) {
  return _.find(array2, function (el2) {
    return el1.indexOf(el2) > 1;
  });
});
```